# MySQL queries via PHP to translate an HTML page in different languages. Good or bad?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm currently working on a website that was already created when I joined the project. I noticed that they use the MySQL database on the server to perform the web page translation. The HTML pages are very straight forward (boxes with selectable data, titles, checkboxes, etc.). The site is a control panel for a specific device; nothing fancy. Everywhere in the HTML there is this type of code to do the translations:

```
    <?php translate("string to translate"); ?>
```

Where the translate() function in a query to MySQL and the PHP session contains the user language information.

For now, the site servers around 400 user (never simultaneously). I'm afraid this is not a scalable solution and as soon as the site will have a decent amount of traffic, it will run like crap.

Is my assumption bad? Should I go with different HTML files for each language (like most web sites, IMO)?

Thanks!

Comment: Different HTML would be far more scalable. Also if you build the template to pull parts in from seperate places, it makes it far easier to build. You could also just use defines for the text and define it in language files.

Comment: Why you dont use **gettext**?

Comment: Yikes, each `translate` is a query?  While MySQL will likely use its query cache, there's still network overhead to consider.  You could pre-render to cache, use [`gettext`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php), or a key-value store like @Loic mentioned all for likely better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems to be hardly scalable and not optimal in a sense that the number of queries you get will grow significantly faster than number of users.

"Should I go with different HTML files for each language (like most web sites, IMO)", no, don't write HTML for each language, that's an old school way to do it and nowadays all sites user templates - one HTML with translatable variables instead of text.

My proposition would be to use one of the frameworks out there, for example Zend or Symfony that have efficient translation mechanisms ready to use out of the box. All your translations would be in a single language file like en_US.po or lt_LT.po and you could edit them using Poedit software.

If you don't want to use framework and want a simpler solution - create a php file for each language with variables containing text, e.g.

en_US.php

```
$translation['page_title'] = 'My cool company title';
$translation['menu_title'] = 'Navigation';
```

lt_LT.php

```
$translation['page_title'] = 'Mano kompanija'; // Lithuanian translation
$translation['menu_title'] = 'Navigacija';     // Lithuanian translation
```

Then include the necessary file before you load HTML and use those variables in the template:

index.php

```
<?php

// Very simple approach to insert the necessary translation file, could be optimized/tuned
if ($_GET['language'] == 'en_US'){
    require 'en_us.php'
}
else if ($_GET['language'] == 'lt_LT'){
    require 'lt_LT.php'
}

?>

<html>
    <title><?= $translation['page_title']; ?></title>
    <body>
    <menu><?= $translation['menu_title']; ?></menu>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This still is bad, because there would be as much file system access as page loads, which is a request. Using mem caching is way faster.

Comment: I agree, it depends how much time speed488 wants to invest into this feature and how many users the system will have to handle in the future

Answer (score 0):

You could use in memory storage for every languages, and then load data from memory.

Check at `Redis`, with it, you can store data as key => value.

Then you could store : "fr.my_key = 'ma clé'", and so on for everything, then store the prefix ('fr' here), in the session.

This would be much faster than your actual solution, consuming less resources, and still way better than creating x templates and reading files on the file system.

Plus I doubt this would require a lot of RAM. Maybe 10 MB if your site is very very big.